# ZAP API scan context file format

Tags: zap

I'm running the [ZAP API scan script](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/docker/api-scan/) on a REST API but I have to host the Open API spec file on my own web server. When I run the scan it logs alerts against the URL where the spec is hosted, I would like to exclude it from the context. I saw that you can provide a context file using the following command line flag

```
-n context_file   context file which will be loaded prior to scanning the target
```

I was wondering where I could find the format of the context file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Launch ZAP desktop, create the context with the details you want, export it and use it in your API scan.